# Simple form (date field) return wrong argument type Hash (expected Array)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a date field and try to use simple_form.

```
<%= f.input :opening_date %>
<%= f.input :opening_date, as: :date %>
```

return always an error : wrong argument type Hash (expected Array). The rails helper date_select work fine.

```
<%= f.date_select :opening_date, order: [:day, :month] %>
```

My field class return
    opening_date.class = Date

Rails : 6.0.2.1.
ruby  : 2.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

You passed :as param with wrong. use string type.
In order to use html5 date fields you can do the following:

```
<%= f.input :opening_date, as: :string, input_html: {type: :date} %>
```

Comment: Hacky and completely unnecessary. You can create HTML5 inputs with `f.input :start_date, as: :date, html5: true` if thats actually the problem here. https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#html-5-notice